# xpath finds nothing - PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

**Introduction**

I have some codes in SQL. I go code by code in while loop in php and search these codes in XML feed.

**Programm code**

I have the following programm code

```
$x_search = $xml->xpath("//Item[@Sort='$sort']");
if(!$x_search){
    $x_Id = $x_search[0]->attributes()->Id;
    echo $sort." - ".$x_Id."<BR />";
}
```

**Problem**

It is possible, that some code is not in SQL. So I get this error message:

```
Undefined offset: 0 in
```

How to do something like if you find it in XML, $x_Id = $x_search[0]->attributes()->Id;?

I have tried already:

1. $x_search = $xml->xpath("//*[@Sort='$sort']");
2. if(!empty($x_search)){
3. if(isset($x_search)){

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Item Id="12860" IdP="-2147483648" Sort="0001KC" Name="Computers">
    <StoItem />
  </Item>
</Root>
```

Examples for `$sort`:

```
00004M
12860
12859
12859
12861
12861
12862
12862
12863
12863
12864
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to include the XML and the value of the `$sort` variable in the question. The messages says that you got an empty array, your Xpath expression did not match any element node.

Comment: @ThW I dont understand what do you mean. Can you give me an example?

Comment: No I can't, your question is missing the XML and part of the expression. I don't know which expression you use on which XML.

Comment: @ThW XML is below my question.

Comment: @ThW And $sort is the variable that contains code in SQL. I need to také the code from SQL, find it in XML and give me an Id from this XML. Problém is if $sort contains the code if it is not in XML. I need to solve this situation.

Comment: show contents of variable $sort

Comment: The condition must be positive `if($x_search){`. And your code works fine. But now with negative confition you ask `$x_search[0]` with `$x_search[0] is = null`

Comment: And if you want only Id, you can use xpath `//Item[@Sort='$sort']/@Id` and then take result as `$x_Id = $x_search[0];`

Comment: @splash58 you are right, the condition must be positive. But the code is still wrong.

Comment: Look there and try with your data https://eval.in/406681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` always returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects. The array is empty, if nothing is matched. The result can equal false, if the expression is invalid (programming error). So `if (!empty($x_search)) ...` or `if ($x_search) ...` can be used as condition to check the result. `false` is an empty value and an empty array equals `false`. Both conditions will only be `true` if the result from the expression is an array with at least a single element.

```
$xmlString = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Item Id="12860" IdP="-2147483648" Sort="0001KC" Name="Computers">
    <StoItem />
  </Item>
</Root>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xmlString);
$sort = '0001KC';

$x_search = $xml->xpath("//Item[@Sort='$sort']");
if (!empty($x_search)) {
    $x_Id = $x_search[0]->attributes()->Id;
    echo $sort." - ".$x_Id."<BR />";
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/406640

```
0001KC - 12860<BR />
```

Most of your example values for `$sort` look like `Id` attribute values. The second one, is the Id attribute value in the example XML.

If you want to match the Id attribute, the Xpath expression would be:

`//Item[@Id='$sort']`

It is even possible to match both attributes:

`//Item[@Id='$sort' or @Sort='$sort']`

Comment: Try the link, it is a working example. I imagine the OP has a different value in `$sort`, that does not match the attribute, so the result is empty. Still `!empty()` would work to avoid the accessing the invalid array element.

Comment: Yes, but how to do if the $sort is for example 00004M and it is not in XML. I need to solve this. Because I need to write this output only if this code is found in XML. If this code is not in XML ignore it.

Comment: xpath returns false while unsuccess.  So your code is not better than code of OP. Say, that sort has incorrect data you can in connent

Comment: No, only a with broken Xpath expression SimpleXMLElement::xpath() will return false. If it does not successful match nodes it will return an empty array. https://eval.in/406656

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the XML. A I wrote it is possible, that some code is not in SQL. So that's why I need to solve this problem. Something like write me an echo only if you find this sort in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
<Item Id="12860" IdP="-2147483648" Sort="0001KC" Name="Computers">
    <StoItem />
</Item>
</Root>
```

The begin of the list of codes that enter invariable $sort

```
00004M
12860
12859
12859
12861
12861
12862
12862
12863
12863
12864
```

Comment: But this is value of id but the first